# Plugin Remote Hosts Access for Gogland

Tags: plugins, ssh, deployment, ide, goland

all!
I have problem with plugin Remote Hosts Access for Gogland which deployment project to remote server after last update.

I full delete IDE and install but problem still have.

I can't find this plugin in plugins menu: com.intellij.modules.ssh

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, there's a module missing which was not shipped with the IDE.

The issue has been discussed and solved [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-4681) and the next EAP. EAP 17, will fix it.